# Meromorphic function with $n+\sqrt{n}$ as poles of second order.

Tags: complex-analysis, meromorphic-functions

Find a meromorphic function with poles at $z_n=n+\sqrt{n}$ with $n\in\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ such that
$$f(z)-\frac{1}{(z-z_n)^2}+\frac{1}{z-z_n}$$
has a removable singularity at $z_n$.

I believe that I have to prove that
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(z-z_n)^2}-\frac{1}{z-z_n}$$
is a meromorphic function; i.e, the series converges uniformly in compacts sets, but I don't know how. Any suggestions?

Comment: this doesn't work because $\sum 1/|z_n| =\infty$ so the order $1$ term doesn't converge; the trick is to notice that  $\sum 1/|z_n|^2$ converges so one adds a correction term and defines $f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty[ \frac{1}{(z-z_n)^2}-(\frac{1}{z-z_n}+1/z_n)]$ so now the order $1$ term is $\sum \frac{z}{(z-z_n)z_n}$ which is absolutely convergent on compact sets in $z$ that avoid $z_n$ since $\sum 1/|z_n|^2=\sum 1/z_n^2$ is convergent

Comment: Thank you @Conrad, I see my mistake and understand your solution.

Comment: happy to help - this works in general for any discrete sequence $z_n$ and any pole orders one wants - though you need to add appropriate correction terms depending on the smallest $k$ for which $\sum 1/|z_n|^k$ converges (if such $k$ doesn't exist, it still can be done but then correction terms are different for different $z_n$); when $z_n$ have symmetry, sometimes one can get rid of the correction terms and get nicer looking series (eg $\tan \pi z$